# Error when trying to append in JTextArea

Tags: java

I tried to append text in the main thread but the following error appeared:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: chatbox.append
at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:41)
```

Here is the full code of my application:

```
package javaapplication3;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;

public class JavaApplication3 extends JFrame {

    public JavaApplication3() {

        setSize(400, 400);
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mypanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
        mypanel.setBounds(10, 10, 300, 300);

        JTextArea chatbox = new JTextArea();
        chatbox.setEditable(false);


        JScrollPane myscrollpane = new JScrollPane(chatbox);
        myscrollpane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

        DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)chatbox.getCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);

        mypanel.add(myscrollpane);
        add(mypanel);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaApplication3 myframe = new JavaApplication3();
        chatbox.append("hi");
    }

}
```

What makes this code not working?

Sorry for my bad English but I hope you understand my problem.

Thank you :)

Comment: What are you using to compile and run this thing?

Comment: You are not just using NetBeans.  You are doing something very weird.  You should not have received the error that you posted above.  You should have received the error that @user3376587 mentioned.  This is a problem for you, and if you do not fix it you are going to be receiving errors that are completely irrelevant to the issues that your code is facing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run it through my compiler, this is what I get.

```
    JavaApplication3.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
            chatbox.append("hi");
            ^
      symbol:   variable chatbox
      location: class JavaApplication3
    1 error
```

Which makes a lot more sense. You instantiated chatbox in the constructor. Thus it is not visible from the main method. You should create the chatbox inside the class but before the constructor.

In other words, make the textField available to whole class instead of just constructor.

```
public class JavaApplication3 extends JFrame {

private final JTextArea chatbox = new JTextArea();

public JavaApplication3() {

    // ... Your stuff

    chatbox.setEditable(false);

    // ... More stuff
}

public appendToChatbox(String s) {
    chatbox.append(s);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JavaApplication3 myframe = new JavaApplication3();
    myframe.appendToChatbox("hi");
}
```

Comment: Only edit this  myframe.appendToChatbox("hi");  to myframe.chatbox.append("hi");
It works like a charm thanks a lot :)